# SoapUI start mock automatically when starting test runner

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui

I have a SoapUI workspace in which I have 5 projects. 4 of them are mock services and the last one is the Web Service I am working on which contains the test runner. For now, I had to start each mock services by hand before running the test suite. So I thought i should automatically start mock services if they aren't yet in order to save a bit of time.

I defined a function in groovy in my Setup Script of the test suite which does the job :

```
def startMockAutomatically(workspace) {

  workspace.getProjectList().each {projects ->
    projects.each {
      project -> project.mockServices.each() {mockService ->

            if (!mockService.value.toString().contains('TestSuiteRunner MockService')) {

               def mockRunner = mockService.value.start();

             if (mockRunner.isRunning()) {
              log.info("Mock Service " + mockService.value + " started");
             }

            }
        }
    }
  }
}


startMockAutomatically(workspace);
```

For now it does the job. However If i open the window of a MockService it doesn't show as started (green arrow is available) and if i try to start it I have an error telling me it's already started. So I don't have any visible feedback that the service is started.

That would be ok for me but as I am working with other developers I would like that to be easy and have some kind of feedback.  I logged something in script log but something at the GUI level would be appreciated.

Also another question, is there a way to test if mock service are already running before starting them ? I could get a mockRunner instance and call isRunning() function after it's started but I would like to do a check before.